# Understanding a calculation of Ricci soliton

Tags: riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Recently, I have read the paper

*Munteanu, Ovidiu; Sesum, Natasa*, [**On gradient Ricci solitons**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s12220-011-9252-6), J. Geom. Anal. 23, No. 2, 539-561 (2013). [ZBL1275.53061](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1275.53061). In that paper at the page 543, there is a calculation, saying that
$$-\int_MR_{ij}f_{ij}e^{-\lambda f}\phi^2=\int_Mf_i\nabla_j(R_{ij}e^{-\lambda f}\phi^2),$$
where $R_{ij}$ is the Ricci tensor, $f\in C^\infty(M)$ and $\phi$ is a cut-off function. Also the author used the fact $\nabla_i(R_{ij}e^{-f})=0$. 
Please tell me the intermediate calculation. I have found that 
$$R_{ij}f_{ij}e^{-\lambda f}\phi^2=\nabla_j(R_{ij}f_ie^{-\lambda f}\phi^2)-f_i\nabla_j(R_{ij}e^{-\lambda f}\phi^2).$$ And by integrating we get an extra term $\int_M\nabla_j(R_{ij}f_ie^{-\lambda f}\phi^2)$. How to prove that this term is zero? 
Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, $\phi$ is compactly supported.  Let $K$ be a sufficiently smooth compact set containing the support of $\phi$.  Then
$$ \int_M \nabla_j (R_{ij}f_i e^{-\lambda f}\phi^2) = \int_K \nabla_j (R_{ij}f_i e^{-\lambda f}\phi^2) = \int_{\partial K} n_j R_{ij}f_i e^{-\lambda f}\phi^2 = 0 . $$
The first equality is because the integrand is zero outside $K$, the second equality follows from the Divergence Theorem, and the third because $\phi$ vanishes on $\partial K$.

Comment: Thank you very much.